# hibernate - junit noob - class variable value lost between 2 test methods

Tags: java, testing, junit

... I got a simple integration test going and all test methods run fine ... BUT...
I set up a class var

```
int tempId;
```

for use by the following methods. testSaveTag() sets the value when successfully executed ( for now everything's auto committed) and the testUpdateTag() updates the freshly created tag.

```
@Test
public void testSaveTag() {
Tag tag = new Tag();
tag.setDescription("Test Tag");
tempId = instance.saveTag(tag);
}

@Test
public void testUpdateTag() {
Tag tag  = instance.getTag(tempId );
tag.setDescription("updated tag description!");
instance.updateTag(tag);
}
```

The value of tempID gets lost between the the 2 methods.

So I'm thinking "What's the proper way to do this",

... and "why is the value lost?"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit test methods should never depend on running in a certain order, and should only share class variables that are not changed by the tests.

In testUpdateTag() you might have to create and save a new tag just to get an ID.  Or is there a way to retrieve a tag that you can then update?

BTW, I hope you are adding assertions at some point...  ;-)

Comment: That's the ticket! Ehm, of course, yes :-) Duh, I can combine those 2 test!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am not the junit expert how ever in most unit test frame works there is a setup and tear down of the system of test which happens between each of your unit test methods.  So your tempId is probably not surviving this process.